# How to retrieve images from the cache in android

Tags: android

here is the code snippet:

```
private static Drawable getDrawableFromUrl(final String url) throws IOException, MalformedURLException {
        URL uurl = new URL(url);
        URLConnection connection = uurl.openConnection();
        connection.setUseCaches(true);  //share cache with browser
        Object response = connection.getContent();
        return Drawable.createFromStream(((InputStream)response), uurl.getFile());
    }
```

So now how do I retrieve it from cache the next time and subsequent times?

Answer (score 2):

`setUseCaches` does not mean the bitmap is cached somewhere... it just controls whether this connection allows to use caches or not.

If you want to use cache for bitmaps I highly recommend using [wasp](https://github.com/telly/wasp) library.